# XML - Rearrange the node in sequence order based on XSD schema using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am trying to arrange the xml node order sequence as per the XSD schema but its not working as expected.
Here am trying to put the  tag in xml as per the xsd schema.
This is the one of the tag.i need to put if the xml comes as input in any sequence need to re arrange as per the schema order as a expected outout
Please help me to resolve.

Either if i want to change the schema to allow the elements in order how do i change with the element in "sequence" in xsd schema.

Input XML

```
<Location>
  <identifier>
    <value value="Ide123" />
  </identifier>
  <managingOrganization>
    <reference value="Test/vaaa" />
  </managingOrganization>
  <name value="Test name" />
 </Location>
```

Expected Output XML:

```
<Location>
  <identifier>
    <value value="Ide123" />
  </identifier>
  <name value="Test name" />
  <managingOrganization>
    <reference value="Test/vaaa" />
  </managingOrganization>
 </Location>
```

Input XSD Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="fhir-base.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="Location" type="Location">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Details and position information for a physical place where services are provided  and resources and participants may be stored, found, contained or accommodated.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="Location">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Details and position information for a physical place where services are provided  and resources and participants may be stored, found, contained or accommodated.</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">If the element is present, it must have either a @value, an @id, or extensions</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="DomainResource">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="identifier" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Identifier">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Unique code or number identifying the location to its users.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="status" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="LocationStatus">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The status property covers the general availability of the resource, not the current value which may be covered by the operationStatus, or by a schedule/slots if they are configured for the location.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="operationalStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="Coding">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The Operational status covers operation values most relevant to beds (but can also apply to rooms/units/chair/etc such as an isolation unit/dialisys chair). This typically covers concepts such as contamination, housekeeping and other activities like maintenance.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Name of the location as used by humans. Does not need to be unique.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="alias" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="string">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">A list of alternate names that the location is known as, or was known as in the past.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="string">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Description of the Location, which helps in finding or referencing the place.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="mode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="LocationMode">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Indicates whether a resource instance represents a specific location or a class of locations.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="CodeableConcept">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Indicates the type of function performed at the location.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="telecom" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="ContactPoint">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The contact details of communication devices available at the location. This can include phone numbers, fax numbers, mobile numbers, email addresses and web sites.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="Address">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Physical location.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="physicalType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="CodeableConcept">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Physical form of the location, e.g. building, room, vehicle, road.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="position" type="Location.Position" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The absolute geographic location of the Location, expressed using the WGS84 datum (This is the same co-ordinate system used in KML).</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="managingOrganization" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="Reference">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">The organization responsible for the provisioning and upkeep of the location.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="partOf" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="Reference">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Another Location which this Location is physically part of.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="endpoint" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Reference">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Technical endpoints providing access to services operated for the location.</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Location.Position">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Details and position information for a physical place where services are provided  and resources and participants may be stored, found, contained or accommodated.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="BackboneElement">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="longitude" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="decimal">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Longitude. The value domain and the interpretation are the same as for the text of the longitude element in KML (see notes below).</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="latitude" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="decimal">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Latitude. The value domain and the interpretation are the same as for the text of the latitude element in KML (see notes below).</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="altitude" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="decimal">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Altitude. The value domain and the interpretation are the same as for the text of the altitude element in KML (see notes below).</xs:documentation>
           </xs:annotation>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="LocationMode-list">
    <xs:restriction base="code-primitive">
      <xs:enumeration value="instance">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Instance</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="kind">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Kind</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="LocationMode">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Indicates whether a resource instance represents a specific location or a class of locations.</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">If the element is present, it must have either a @value, an @id, or extensions</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Element">
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="LocationMode-list" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="LocationStatus-list">
    <xs:restriction base="code-primitive">
      <xs:enumeration value="active">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Active</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="suspended">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Suspended</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="inactive">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Inactive</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:complexType name="LocationStatus">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Indicates whether the location is still in use.</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">If the element is present, it must have either a @value, an @id, or extensions</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Element">
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="LocationStatus-list" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XSLT Code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="kxsElemByName" match="xs:element" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:key name="kxsTypeByName" match="xs:complexType" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vSchema" select="document('file:///C:/Users/310271854/Amina/location.xsd')"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vSchema">
                <xsl:variable name="element" select="key('kxsElemByName', name($current))" />
                <xsl:variable name="complexContent" select="key('kxsTypeByName', $element/@name)" />
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$complexContent">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$complexContent/xs:extension/xs:sequence/xs:element">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$current/*[name() = current()/@name]" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$current/node()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That schema has a target namespace while the input snippet you show does not use any namespace at all. Furthermore the schema has an `xs:include`, how do you expect to handle that in your XSLT code?

Comment: Thanks for your response @MartinHonnen.Here i have tried removing target name space as well but it didn't work as expected.Please provide any other solution to get the expected output.That would be very helpful.